# Static files 404 not found error with ssl - Django + uWSGI + nginx

Tags: django, ssl, nginx, uwsgi, lets-encrypt

I have a nginx server with my site enabled which is listening on 443 and forwarding traffic to my django app server which is using uWSGI. I can get to the admin page and log in but not static files are served. I've ran `python3 manage.py collectstatic`. Everything worked before adding SSL with `letsencrypt`. Getting this in the nginx access logs:

```
"GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.0" 404
```

Here's my reverse proxy nginx site config:

```
upstream staging_app_server {
    server 52.52.52.52;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name staging.site.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*)  https://staging.site.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {

    listen 443;
    server_name staging.site.com;

    include snippets/ssl-staging.site.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/staging.access.log;

    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_pass          http://staging_app_server;
      proxy_redirect      http://staging_app_server https://staging_app_server;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
    }

  }
```

And the app server nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name staging.site.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/ubuntu/api/staticfiles;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/ubuntu/api/media;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/run/uwsgi/api.sock;
        uwsgi_param     UWSGI_SCHEME $scheme;
        uwsgi_param       Host $host;
        uwsgi_param       X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        uwsgi_param       X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        uwsgi_param       X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        uwsgi_param       X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I hope you run the collectstatic command in the server so that the static files will be collected at your specified folder.

Comment: The command `python3 manage.py collectstatic` has been ran. There's files in `/home/ubuntu/api/staticfiles`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `alias` statements are wrong. Either both the value of the `location` and the value of the `alias` should end in `/` or neither end in `/`.

Also, use `root` where the `alias` value ends with the `location` value. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

For example:

```
location /static/ {
    alias /home/ubuntu/api/staticfiles/;
}
location /media/ {
    root /home/ubuntu/api;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
location /static {
    autoindex on;
    alias  /home/ubuntu/api/staticfiles;
}
```

Thanks to @richard-smith for pointing me in the right direction!